# am trying to install runtime fabric on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, mule, anypoint-rtf

Am trying to install Runtime Fabric on AWS, am using this document as guide : https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.11/install-aws , but when am running this command

```
terraform apply \
  -var activation_data='' \
  -var key_pair='' \
  -var enable_public_ips='' \
  -var controllers='3' \
  -var workers='3' \
  -var mule_license='' \
  -state=tf-data/rtf.tfstate
```

am getting below error

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on fabric.tf line 387, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 387:   map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ips
    |----------------
    | var.enable_public_ips is ""

Inappropriate value for attribute "map_public_ip_on_launch": a bool is
required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on fabric.tf line 387, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 387:   map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ips
    |----------------
    | var.enable_public_ips is ""

Inappropriate value for attribute "map_public_ip_on_launch": a bool is
required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on fabric.tf line 387, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 387:   map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ips
    |----------------
    | var.enable_public_ips is ""

Inappropriate value for attribute "map_public_ip_on_launch": a bool is
required.


Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on fabric.tf line 387, in resource "aws_subnet" "public":
 387:   map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ips
    |----------------
    | var.enable_public_ips is ""

Inappropriate value for attribute "map_public_ip_on_launch": a bool is
required.
```

the file am running is called fabric.tf and this is the line " map_public_ip_on_launch = var.enable_public_ips" & variable "enable_public_ips" {
default = true
}

which is creating problem, can anyone help ?

Comment: The problem is you are providing values of wrong type to variables. Please add some Terraform code, the error itself is not enough to make an educated guess about what else could be wrong. You should at the very least omit the `-var enable_public_ips=''` from the command. Or if you don't want public IPs then set it to `false`, i.e., `-var enable_public_ips=false`.

Comment: Are you following the instructions? You are supposed to modify the script and replace the empty values (https://docs.mulesoft.com/runtime-fabric/1.11/install-aws#run-using-native-terraform) If you don't follow the instructions to the letter you can expect problems. Just copying and pasting random snippets will not work.